# JQuery Datepicker: show on input group addon button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have the following `div`:

```
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="hidden" id="datepicker">
                <input type="text" id="input_date" class="form-control" value="" readonly='readonly'>
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="input_btn_calendar"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
```

And the following JQuery call:

```
    var today = new Date();
    $("#input_date").datepicker({
        changeYear: false,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        altField: "#datepicker",
        minDate: today,
        onSelect : function () {
            var inputdate = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', $("#datepicker").val());
        }
    }).datepicker("setDate",today);
```

This makes the `datepicker` appear correctly when I press the `text` field. However, I also want it to show up when I click the `input_btn_calendar` button inside the accompanying span.

I've tried this:

```
    $("#input_btn_calendar").click(function() {
        $("input_date").datepicker('show')
    });
```

But unfortunately, that does nothing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an invalid selector of `$('input_date')`.

Try this instead,

```
$("#input_btn_calendar").click(function() {
    $("#input_date").datepicker('show')
});
```

Comment: D'oh. Thanks for noticing it quickly. I'm working on a codebase over a network share so my syntax highlighting can sometimes take a couple minutes...